# JobIntentService not Starting properly in Some Devices?

Tags: android, android-intentservice, jobintentservice

Previously am using `IntentService` to trigger the Background services with AlaramManager. Now am changed the `IntentService` to `JobIntentService` for trigger Background process to fetch the data from Server. In Some devices `JobIntentService` not triggering, it will trigger only after open the application.

**Set AlaramManager**

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

PendingIntent pi;
AlarmManager am;

pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), requestCode, new Intent(getActivity(), PendingCampaignReceiver.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

am = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
```

**BroadCastReceiver Class**

```
public class PendingCampaignReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        PendingCampaign.enqueueWork(context, intent);
    }
}

<receiver
        android:name=".broadcast.receiver.PendingCampaignReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:process=":remote" />
```

**JobIntentService Class**

```
public class PendingCampaign extends JobIntentService {

 public static void enqueueWork(Context context, Intent intent) {
    enqueueWork(context, PendingCampaign.class, PENDING_CAMPAIGN_JOB_ID, intent);
 }

  @Override
 protected void onHandleWork(@NonNull Intent intent) {

    //am doing my API calling here

 }
}

<service
        android:name=".services.PendingCampaign"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
```

Is there any issue in my Coding. Help me to solve the issue.